# COUNT & PRINT matched Row values in NEW COLUMNS

Tags: sql, pivot

I am trying to make the column name from row value and count the total value of each row name to show into the particular column name. Result will show from 30 days.

```
SELECT id
, Name
, Designation 
, DeptName
, Sts
, COUNT(Sts) as 'COUNT'
FROM table
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())
AND Name = 'Neo'
GROUP BY id, Name, Designation, DeptName, Sts
ORDER id
```

Here is my output

[image]

Required Output is...

[image]

Comment: Use `PIVOT()` function

Comment: Which rdbms engine? Oracle, SQLServer, PostrgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
    SELECT id
    , Name
    , Designation 
    , DeptName        
    , sum (case when Sts='H' then 1 end) H
,sum (case when Sts='A' then 1 end) A
,sum (case when Sts='P' then 1 end)  P
    FROM table
    WHERE Date >= DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())
    AND Name = 'Neo'
    GROUP BY id, Name, Designation, DeptName
    ORDER id
```

The CASE statement goes through conditions and return a value when the first condition is met (like an IF-THEN-ELSE statement) and when a condition will meet it will sum up for that particular value

Comment: What will be the behaviour of `SUM()` in `else` part of `case` statement .

Comment: I have done what you suggested and the output is not coming in single row. Need to show them in a single row for each person. Getting NULL values for blank column for each row.

Comment: @John there is now way to create multiple row if you not used sts in group by , you have to group by using column id,name ,designation.deptname

Answer (score 0):

As eariler suggested, use pivot

```
WITH temp AS(
SELECT 1 AS id,'Neo' AS name,'Zonal Manager' AS designation, 'Admin' AS deptname, 'H' AS sts ,2 AS cnt FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Neo','Zonal Manager', 'Admin', 'A',3 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Neo','Zonal Manager', 'Admin', 'P',4 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Neo','Zonal Manager', 'Admin', 'A',1 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Neo','Zonal Manager', 'Admin', 'A',8 FROM dual )
SELECT p.*
FROM   temp
PIVOT(
       SUM(cnt)
       FOR sts 
       IN  ('A', 'P', 'H')
     ) p
```